# Firemonkey TFrame Align = Scale Bug?

Tags: delphi, scale, frame, firemonkey

I have a doubt. I have created a Frame in firemonkey and added 2 buttons, then inside MainForm I added this Frame.

```
Frame.Align = Scale
```

In the MainForm the Object `Frame.Align = Client`

When I compile and resize the Form, the Frame does not scale.

Is this a normal question or a bug?

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 481
  ClientWidth = 627
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  inline Frame21: TFrame2
    Align = Scale
    Position.Y = -3.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 887.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 653.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
end

object Frame2: TFrame2
  Align = Scale
  Size.Width = 526.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 395.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 80.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'Button1'
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Position.X = 144.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 144.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Button2'
  end
  object Button3: TButton
    Position.X = 240.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 256.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 2
    Text = 'Button3'
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you understand by the term 'scale'? What are you expecting/trying to achieve?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nom90rfahb1c0m/capture-7.mp4?dl=0

Comment: the relative controls, should not resize?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Delphi XE7. The frame (and components with `Scale`) resizes as expected. Please show your form as text (Right on form view and select `Show as text`)

Comment: Hi Tom Brunberg

Can you share your example for download?

I'll show the DFM in a few minutes thanks.

Comment: Hi Wesley, I think you have got this site wrong. You are supposed to show your code for evaluation. So far I can see only two statements, without any context. I had to guess what you are doing, I might have misunderstood. So, I remain waiting for your response to my previous comment.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eGUsYXa7

Comment: Please npte Wesley, that ALL information related to the question MUST be in the question post. Links to external sites may become invalid, thus rendering your question worthless for future readers. This time I copied the .fmx content into your question for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no bug with `Align = Scale` in a frame. You seem to have only the frame itself aligned with `Scale`.

If you want the components on the frame also to scale, you need to assign their `Align` property as well.

Here's my form

```
object Form22: TForm22
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form22'
  ClientHeight = 200
  ClientWidth = 350
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  inline Frame221: TFrame22
    Align = Scale
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 14.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 320.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 171.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
    inherited Label1: TLabel
      Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    end
    inherited Button1: TButton
      Position.Y = 48.857139587402340000
      Size.Height = 19.193893432617190000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    inherited Button2: TButton
      Position.Y = 48.857139587402340000
      Size.Height = 19.193893432617190000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
    end
    inherited Rectangle1: TRectangle
      Position.Y = 76.775512695312500000
      Size.Height = 77.647918701171880000
    end
  end
end
```

And the frame

```
object Frame22: TFrame22
  Align = Scale
  Size.Width = 320.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 196.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  TabOrder = 0
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.X = 32.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 32.000000000000000000
    Text = 'Frame here!'
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Align = Scale
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Button1'
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Align = Scale
    Position.X = 216.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 2
    Text = 'Button2'
  end
  object Rectangle1: TRectangle
    Align = Scale
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 88.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 281.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 89.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
end
```

Note that all components (except the `TLabel`) have their `Align` property set to `Scale`.